# How to check if a Storyboard exists in a specific NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, nsbundle

I'm making an app that makes use of a framework that I'm creating.

The framework contains storyboards but in some cases the project making use of the framework will need to override the storyboard by providing a new one.

So my goal is to check if a storyboard with a given name exists in `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, if not then I will get the base version from my framework.

I have tried getting the storyboard from the main bundle and checking for the result being nil but it throws an exception if it can't find it. So I then tried to catch the exception and then load the storyboard from the framework. This **does** work but it feels dirty and it could well hit the performance of my app.

I have also tried `pathForResource` in the bundle:

```
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"storyboard"] != nil) {

}
```

But this never finds the storyboard.

Does anyone know of any other way that I can check if a storyboard exists in a specific bundle?

Comment: Since you cannot write into the application bundle at runtime you are supposed to know exactly what's in the bundle at compile time...

Comment: The code is in the framework. So i cannot tell from the framework what's in the main bundle that it's been embedded into..

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but a compiled storyboard has a file extension of "storyboardc".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, I was nearly there with what I was already trying. As per a comment on my question, the compiled extension for a storyboard is "storyboardc". So I can check whether or not a storyboard exists in a bundle like so:

```
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"storyboardc"] != nil) {
    //The storyboard exists
} else {
    //The storyboard isn't in the bundle, get it from the framework bundle.
}
```

Comment: The "c" in `storyboardc` is important since we're looking for the compiler storyboard file !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, @Swinny89 Do you know if the usage of `storyboardc` is a rejection reason for the AppStore?

Comment: It not a use of a private API so, no.

Comment: `pathForResource:name ofType:@"storyboardc` doesn't work on devices and I had to resubmit an app. DO NOT USE IT.

Comment: Please can you provide more information on this? I've used this is apps running on devices for a long time and have never come across any issue.

Answer (score 1):

> 

### **Swift:**

```
if Bundle.main.path(forResource: storyboardName, ofType: "storyboardc") != nil 
{
   //The storyboard exists
}
```

Comment: Hello. This is a bit off-topic, and not optimal. The question is about Objective-C (look at the tags) so Swift is off-topic here. Also in Swift you should unwrap with `if let` instead of comparing to nil like in Objective-C.