# How to check a storyboard id exists or not

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my `rootTableViewCobtroller` , I want make a generic method . When I select cell,`rootTableViewCobtroller`  push one of all of my other ViewControllers (named certain rules)

When I select cell , do push action:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"List%ld",indexPath.row+1];
    Class vcClass = NSClassFromString(string);
    UIViewController *vc = [[vcClass alloc]init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

So my other ViewControllers's class name is `List1,list2,List3...`

#### Qusetion:

In the above code ，I just initial viewcontroller using code .For some reason ,for a few viewcontroller, I use storyboard file associated with it .The storyboard file ,corresponding to each other named it's storyboard id is same as class name

**e.g:**

List1 not has a storyboard file,I should creat List1 instance through

```
 List1 *list1VC =    [[List1 alloc]init];
```

List2 not has a storyboard file,I should creat List2 instance through

```
List2 *list2VC =   [[List2 alloc]init];
```

List3 has a storyboard file ,name it's storyboard file's storyboard id `List3`.I should creat List1 instance through

```
 List3 *list3VC =   [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"List3"];
```

So I should modify my generic method like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"List%ld",indexPath.row+1];
    Class vcClass = NSClassFromString(string);
    UIViewController *vc;

    //**if storyboard contain a file with storyboard id is equal to "string"**
    if ([self.storyboard contain_storyboard_id:  string]){
       vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:string];
    }else{
   vc = [[vcClass alloc]init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
```

**But how to check  a storyboard id exists or not, If I donot check whether a class has associated storyboard file just use
`[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:string]`while crash my app.**

Comment: This way you can get storyboard Id NSString *restorationId = self.restorationIdentifier

Comment: I would have your view controller subclasses implement a class function that indicates whether they should be created from a storyboard or not (actually, I would just use a storyboard for everything)

Comment: you can Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590288/how-to-check-if-a-storyboard-exists-in-a-specific-nsbundle

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708660/programmatically-get-a-storyboard-id

Comment: @prasad   `restorationIdentifier`  will cause other additional work for app,may have other performance issues.

Comment: @prasad, neither of those do what the OP is after; the first checks for the existence of a storyboard file (I guess they could a storyboard per view controller and name it appropriately) while the second lets a view controller instance determine if it came from a storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11 Cause  controller  instance not created ,we cannot use controller's storyboard determine if it came from a storyboard.I use your first   suggestion ,this sound great ,but if I just add class method though category, this leads to another problem [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736049/how-to-override-a-oc-category-method-in-swift/42736858#42736858) (I both use swift and oc)